# Filter a fixed amount of data using AutoFilter

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I would like to filter only a fixed amount of data. I am implementing a code posted on this WebPage and it works perfectly, but it filters all the data that contain "Item1" and "Approved". For example, what I would like to do is to filter only 5 rows of data with the given conditions instead of filtering all.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim OriginalData As Worksheet, FilteredData As Worksheet

    Set OriginalData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set FilteredData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With OriginalData
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion
             .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Item1"

             .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="Approved"
             With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .Copy Destination:= _
                        FilteredData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                End If
              End With
         End With
         If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Filter everything then grab first five rows?

Comment: That code looks familiar. Are your column header labels in hte first row or the second? If in the second, the CurrentRegion property may not be giving you the correct range.

Comment: lol @Jeeped ^_^ How you remember something you wrote half a year [ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063401/vba-excel-iterating-through-cells-selected-in-filtered-column).

Comment: @Jeeped It is indeed your code from another threat, I have been trying a lot by myself and none worked and I saw yours and it worked perfectly!!,

Comment: @findwindow - I'm the only one I know that uses CBool to convert a Subtotal's count of visible rows into a boolean. I'm also big on [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) as a quick method of referencing data blocks radiating out from A1.

Comment: @Jeeped pffft adding `cbool` to all my code going forward.

Comment: @Jeeped well, your code prowess is intimidating =P

Comment: Getting back to the question at hand, [.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) can isolate the first 5 rows before filtering but you would need to use [.Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx) to get the first 5 filtered rows. Again, CurrentRegion may not be giving you the correct filter range if your data starts in the third row. Select A2 and tap [ctrl]+A - is that what you want as the filter range (keep in mind that AutoFilter required a row for headers even if that row is blank).

Comment: @Jeeped My data starts in the second row,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter the first 5 rows then the [Range.Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) can be applied to the [.CurrentRegion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) before the [.AutoFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) method.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim OriginalData As Worksheet, FilteredData As Worksheet

    Set OriginalData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set FilteredData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With OriginalData
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion   'all cells radiating out from A1
            'resize to 6 rows total (5 data + 1 header)
            With .Resize(6, .Columns.Count)
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Item1"
                .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="Approved"
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                        .Copy Destination:= _
                            FilteredData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    End If
                End With
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that if you step through the code with <kbd>F8</kbd> all of the data will actually be filtered but only filtered data from the first 5 (visible or not visible) rows will be copied.

If you want to copy the first 5 filtered rows then you need to deal with the non-contiguous visible [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx) and some maths.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim a As Long, aa As Long
    Dim OriginalData As Worksheet, FilteredData As Worksheet

    Set OriginalData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set FilteredData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    aa = 5

    With OriginalData
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion   'all cells radiating out from A1
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Item1"
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Approved"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                        For a = 1 To .Areas.Count
                            .Areas(a).Resize(Application.Min(aa, .Areas(a).Rows.Count), .Columns.Count).Copy Destination:= _
                                FilteredData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                            aa = aa - Application.Min(aa, .Areas(a).Rows.Count)
                            If aa < 1 Then Exit For
                        Next a
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Both of those survive my limited testing. Post back if you run into problems I have not accounted for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, They worked perfectly!! I am inclined toward the second method